# install Karma ECONNREFUSED

Tags: karma-runner

I trie to install karma but get the error bellow. I already did a npm set http_proxy and https_proxy.

Any ideas?

Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect ECONNREFUSED

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
npm config set registry="http://registry.npmjs.org/"
```

It worked for me.